# CoffeeScript function issue

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

i am new to coffeescript. i have already written code in `js`, now i want to convert it in `coffeescript`,i have try a lot,i have refer [This](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow) also. but it won't help me.

here is my code,

```
this.$scope.callTestFuntion = function(){
    this.blockingObject.render(function(dataURL){
      console.log('via render');
      console.log(dataURL.length);
    });
  }
  this.$scope.blockingObject.callback=function(dataURL){
    console.log('via function');
    console.log(dataURL.length);
    this.myCroppedImage = dataURL;
  }

  var handleFileSelect=function(evt) {
    console.log('here');
    var file=evt.currentTarget.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (evt) {
        this.$scope.$apply(function($scope){
        this.$scope.myImage=evt.target.result;
      });
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  };
```

I want to convert it in coffeescript syntax. please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to convert JS to coffescript, wich eventually/inevitably will be converted back to JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to convert the code then use  http://js2.coffee

```
@$scope.callTestFuntion = ->
  @blockingObject.render (dataURL) ->
    console.log 'via render'
    console.log dataURL.length
    return
  return

@$scope.blockingObject.callback = (dataURL) ->
  console.log 'via function'
  console.log dataURL.length
  @myCroppedImage = dataURL
  return

handleFileSelect = (evt) ->
  console.log 'here'
  file = evt.currentTarget.files[0]
  reader = new FileReader

  reader.onload = (evt) ->
    @$scope.$apply ($scope) ->
      @$scope.myImage = evt.target.result
      return
    return

  reader.readAsDataURL file
  return

# ---
# generated by js2coffee 2.2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your converted code:

```
# CoffeeScript code converted from JavaScript
# from Georgi Naumov
# gonaumov@gmail.com for contacts and suggestions
@.$scope.callTestFuntion = ->
  @.blockingObject.render (dataURL) ->
    console.log 'via render'
    console.log dataURL.length
@.$scope.blockingObject.callback = (dataURL) ->
  console.log 'via function'
  console.log dataURL.length
  @.myCroppedImage = dataURL

handleFileSelect = (evt) ->
  console.log 'here'
  file = evt.currentTarget.files[0]
  reader = new FileReader()
  reader.onload = (evt) ->
    @.$scope.$apply ($scope) ->
      @.$scope.myImage = evt.target.result
  reader.readAsDataURL file
```

And here is resulted JavaScript after compilation:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.12.3
(function() {
  var handleFileSelect;

  this.$scope.callTestFuntion = function() {
    return this.blockingObject.render(function(dataURL) {
      console.log('via render');
      return console.log(dataURL.length);
    });
  };

  this.$scope.blockingObject.callback = function(dataURL) {
    console.log('via function');
    console.log(dataURL.length);
    return this.myCroppedImage = dataURL;
  };

  handleFileSelect = function(evt) {
    var file, reader;
    console.log('here');
    file = evt.currentTarget.files[0];
    reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(evt) {
      return this.$scope.$apply(function($scope) {
        return this.$scope.myImage = evt.target.result;
      });
    };
    return reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  };

}).call(this);
```

Comment: I just fixed one issue with redundant return of function. Good luck :)